# C# Thread.Sleep(ms) Freezes UI and I can't use Alternative Options

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, delay, sleep

I am Making C# WPF Application That contains CSV Writing.

But, I wanna give some delays. But When i use 
`Thread.Sleep(ms)`,
UI freezes and Windows says that This Program has been Stopped.

So, I found some Alternatives like

```
private static DateTime Delay(int MS)
     {
         DateTime ThisMoment = DateTime.Now;
         TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, MS);
         DateTime AfterWards = ThisMoment.Add(duration);
         while (AfterWards >= ThisMoment)
         {
             if (System.Windows.Application.Current != null)
             {
                 System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(delegate { }));
             }
             ThisMoment = DateTime.Now;
         }
         return DateTime.Now;
     }
```

But,when I use this method, The Program just Stops.

This is Button Code that makes, writes CSV File.

```
 private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"New.csv");
            int a = 1;
            file.WriteLine("Delta, Theta");
            while (a < 20)
            {

                file.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", TGLatestData.EegPowerDelta, TGLatestData.EegPowerTheta);
                a++;
                file.Close();
                Thread.Sleep(3000);    //Delay(3000); When I use Alternative way.
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Broken", ex);
        }
    }
```

The Main Question that I want to know is how to delay some seconds without Freezing UI. Sorry for Bad Grammar.

Comment: I think the question is _why do you want to sleep for `3 seconds` after clicking a button and writing to a file?_ .  Also, your code won't work because the `file.Close()` is inside the loop, thus the next `file.WriteLine()` will fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your click handler async. Then you can use `Task.Delay`, which will not block the thread.

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"New.csv");
        int a = 1;
        file.WriteLine("Delta, Theta");
        while (a < 20)
        {
            file.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", TGLatestData.EegPowerDelta, TGLatestData.EegPowerTheta);
            a++;
            file.Close();
            await Task.Delay(3000);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Broken", ex);
    }
}
```

By the way, here's one way to fix your exception:

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    const string fileName = @"New.csv";
    try
    {
        File.AppendAllText(fileName, "Delta, Theta");
        for (var a=1; a<20; a++)
        {
            var text = string.Format("{0}, {1}", TGLatestData.EegPowerDelta, TGLatestData.EegPowerTheta);
            File.AppendAllText(fileName, text);
            await Task.Delay(3000);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Broken", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but, I already did that way but, after 3seconds, Windows says that the program stopped. Is there other alternatives to delay?

Comment: This is the correct way. You should probably figure out why the program stopped, e.g. if you have an unhandled exception, and handle it. In your code example, it appears you close the file and never re-open it before trying to write to it again, so of course it will fail.

Comment: Why are you writing and then closing the file in a loop? When it comes around its not going to work. Also writing to the file isn't asnyc, so it will block. Using async handler still isn't going to work.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ For clarity, my code example only includes modifications to answer the OP's specific question, not to correct all of their issues.

Comment: If I don't write that Close Code in 'while function', The program doesn't write Datas in CSV File.

Comment: Thx and I will fix it hard as i con using this method :D

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I was foolish. If I write Close() Code outside 'while function', I should wait time to close the file after while function. Thank you so much to give me that sharp Question. Finally I got it! :D

Comment: @JohnWu I finally adopt your code. Thank you so much to give me nice tip! :D

Comment: If you want more `async` goodness there is a rather groovy `File.AppendAllTextAsync`

Comment: @WooYoungChoi could you please edit question so answer actually answers it? Clearly you wanted some sort of delay (like 1 minute in original code)... while this answer shows how to add some sort of delay it is unclear how it related to the question... (John Wu - consider editing question too).

Answer (score 0):

```
 private async void CSVexport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  //to use Await Task.Delay(ms) Option
    {

        try
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveAsfile = new SaveFileDialog();  //Save As File

            saveAsfile.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            saveAsfile.Title = "Save As File";
            saveAsfile.Filter = "CSV Document(*.csv)|*.csv|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
            saveAsfile.DefaultExt = "csv";
            saveAsfile.AddExtension = true;
            if (saveAsfile.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)  //Save As File Function
            {
                GaugeSignal.Value = 1;
                if (TGLatestData.PoorSignal != -1)
                {
                    var SignalQuality = Math.Round((200D - TGLatestData.PoorSignal) / 2D, 1);
                    if (SignalQuality < 0) SignalQuality = 0;
                    GaugeSignal.Value = SignalQuality;
                    TGLatestData.PoorSignal = TGLatestData.PoorSignal;
                }
                SQZero.Visibility = 0;
                CSVexport.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                FileStream filestream = new FileStream(saveAsfile.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("CSV Writing...\nIf you want to stop Writing CSV, Click SQ to 0 Button,", "CSV Writing...", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filestream);
                int time = 1000;
                file.WriteLine("Signal Quality, Delta, Theta, Alpha1, Alpha2, Beta1, Beta2, Gamma1, Gamma2, Attention, Meditation, Mental Effort, Task Familiarity, Task Difficulty, Blink Strength");
                while (true)  //infinite loop
                {
                    double Check_Signal_Zero_To_Stop = GaugeSignal.Value;
                    file.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}, {12}, {13}, {14}", GaugeSignal.Value, TGLatestData.EegPowerDelta, TGLatestData.EegPowerTheta, TGLatestData.EegPowerAlpha1, TGLatestData.EegPowerAlpha2, TGLatestData.EegPowerBeta1, TGLatestData.EegPowerBeta2, TGLatestData.EegPowerGamma1, TGLatestData.EegPowerGamma2, TGLatestData.Attention, TGLatestData.Meditation, TGLatestData.MentalEffort, TGLatestData.TaskFamiliarity, TGLatestData.TaskDifficulty, TGLatestData.BlinkStrength);
                    await Task.Delay(time);  //Delay Without FreezingUI (need async)
                    if (Check_Signal_Zero_To_Stop == 0)
                    {
                        file.Close();  //if you click SQ to 0, Do file.Close
                        while (true) await Task.Delay(1000000000); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("This Program is Get Broken", ex);
        }
    }
```

I changed `private void` to 'private async void' to use `Await Task.Delay(ms)` instead of `Thread.Sleep(ms)` and I also Made Stop Button to get out of infinite loop.
Here is SQ to 0 Button Source. If you Click this button, One variable(GaugeSignal.Value) will be 0 and it will stop Writing CSV and Saving modified file.

```
 private async void SQzero_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int EndTime = 4000;
        SQZero.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Stop Writing CSV... \nWait a Seconds..", "CSV Saving..", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        GaugeSignal.Value = 0;
        await Task.Delay(EndTime);    //Wait for Delay of CSVexport_btn
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("CSV Saved!", "CSV Saved", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        CSVexport.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;  //to Save another one Again
    }
```

I was Foolish. I used `file.Close();` in loop. So, It says IOException. I found other method to avoid them and Finally got it. Thanks to  John Wu, Çöđěxěŕ to help me.